# Bar chart of proportion of a value in differents columns

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

New in R and discover the tidyverse :)

I've this data :

```
# A tibble: 169 x 14
   `Nitrous oxide ~ `Fentanyl (choi~ `Ketamine (choi~ `Ketamine (choi~ `Propofol (choi~ `Dexmedetomidin~
   <chr>            <chr>            <chr>            <chr>            <chr>            <chr>           
 1 Unchecked        Unchecked        Checked          Unchecked        Unchecked        Unchecked       
 2 Unchecked        Unchecked        Checked          Unchecked        Unchecked        Unchecked       
 3 Unchecked        Checked          Checked          Checked          Checked          Unchecked       
 4 Checked          Checked          Checked          Checked          Checked          Unchecked       
 5 Checked          Unchecked        Checked          Unchecked        Checked          Unchecked       
 6 Checked          Unchecked        Checked          Unchecked        Checked          Unchecked       
 7 Checked          Checked          Checked          Checked          Checked          Unchecked       
 8 Checked          Checked          Checked          Checked          Checked          Checked         
 9 Checked          Checked          Checked          Checked          Checked          Unchecked       
10 Unchecked        Checked          Checked          Unchecked        Checked          Unchecked
```

This is the result of a survey, the values are "checked" or "unchecked", the rows are one person who answers, and the columns are the questions.

I want to make a bar chart of the proportion of "checked" for every question.

I understand i must transform my table, probably for something like that :

```
   Name            % of checked
`Nitrous oxide ~   72.35
`Fentanyl (choi~   18.25
`Ketamine (choi~   25.68 
`Ketamine (choi~   26.98 
`Propofol (choi~   15.25 
`Dexmedetomidin~   95.36
```

This is just for example, false numbers. I can't make this transformation.
After that, i had to use ggplot with geom_bar, i think.

Could you help me ? I try count and summarize, mutate ... but doesn't work, and I've no solution :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an option using the tidyverse since that seems to be your preference.

I've generated a little test data to show you the principle and have named the variables a little more simply than your use case:

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(500)
choices <- c("Unchecked", "Checked")
rows <- 20

df <- data.frame(q1 = sample(choices, rows, replace = TRUE),
                 q2 = sample(choices, rows, replace = TRUE),
                 q3 = sample(choices, rows, replace = TRUE),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

The code below will convert your data from a wide format to a long format. I only have three example variables, so you would need to adjust `r cols = 1:3` to include all 5 columns you have. Following that, mutate generates a logical variable based on your data, then group_by and summarise calculate a question specific mean value of responses. Finally, a very simple ggplot bar graph.

```
df %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = 1:3, 
                      names_to = "question") %>% 
  mutate(result = value == "Checked") %>% 
  group_by(question) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(result)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = question,
             y = mean)) +
  geom_col()
```

Comment: I finnaly understand !
- with pivot_longer, you finally obtain a tidy table, which was hard to understand for me
- with mutate you add a column which convert "Checked" in TRUE ou FALSE
- with group_by, you obtain the table i want in my question
- with summarise, you use mean to calcylate the proportion. I had hard time to understand, but mean convert TRUE in "1", then it give the (sum of 1)/total 
Thanks !

Comment: Glad I could help @Aytan

Answer (score 1):

Try this. First. Convert to long format via `pivot_longer`. Then do the computations via `count`, `add_count` and `mutate` (you could also use `summarise`, but `count` is more concise). Next `filter` for `Checked` and finally plot:

```r
df <- read.table(text = "id   'Nitrous oxide~'  'Fentanyl (choi~ ' 'Ketamine (choi~' 'Ketamine (choi~' 'Propofol (choi~' 'Dexmedetomidin~'
 1 Unchecked        Unchecked        Checked          Unchecked        Unchecked        Unchecked       
 2 Unchecked        Unchecked        Checked          Unchecked        Unchecked        Unchecked       
 3 Unchecked        Checked          Checked          Checked          Checked          Unchecked       
 4 Checked          Checked          Checked          Checked          Checked          Unchecked       
 5 Checked          Unchecked        Checked          Unchecked        Checked          Unchecked       
 6 Checked          Unchecked        Checked          Unchecked        Checked          Unchecked       
 7 Checked          Checked          Checked          Checked          Checked          Unchecked       
 8 Checked          Checked          Checked          Checked          Checked          Checked         
 9 Checked          Checked          Checked          Checked          Checked          Unchecked       
10 Unchecked        Checked          Checked          Unchecked        Checked          Unchecked ", header = TRUE)

df <- select(df, -id)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "var", values_to = "status") %>% 
  count(var, status) %>% 
  add_count(var, wt = n, name = "total") %>% 
  mutate(pct = n / total) %>% 
  filter(status == "Checked") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(var, pct, fill = var)) +
  geom_col() + 
  guides(fill = FALSE) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would tackle this by changing all the `checked` and `unchecked` values to 1 and 0 respectively. Then you could use the `purrr:map` function to sum and create the percentages by column, and then pipe into a barchart.

```
dataframe[datframe=="Checked"]==1
dataframe[dataframe=="Unchecked"]==0

dataframe %>%
  mutate_all(as.numeric) %>%
  map_df(~data.frame(Percentage = sum(.x)/length(.x)),
         .id = 'colnames') %>%
ggplot(aes(colnames, Percentage)) +
geom_col()
```